# Microsoft WinForms Chart Control - Set Position of Y-Axis Label

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a Y-Axis Label as shown here:

[image]

I am trying to position the label closer to the chart, is there any facility to do this?

I could add a Winforms Label and position it accordingly but just in case there is a better way.

Comment: Axis.CustomLabels, perhaps.

Comment: MS developers... The offset should be configurable, this is far from 0 offset. Sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the `AxisY.Title AvGkW` you can't position it other than aligning it `near, center, far`.

But you can add as many `Titles` to your `Chart` as you want, dock them to all four corners of the earth, um, `Chart`, style them and set their offset..

After you have added your `Title` like this:

```
Title TT = new Title( yourTitleText, Docking.Left, yourFont, yourcolor);
TT.Docking = Docking.Left;
yourChart.Titles.Add(TT);
```

You can move it left and right like this:

```
TT.DockingOffset = yourOffset;
```

It isn't in the specs here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.title.dockingoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but as usual it is in 1/100 of the `Chart.Size`, so setting it to `50` moves the `Title` into the middle of the `ChartArea`.. It is an `int32` strangely!

You will have to play with the number depending on the size of the `Y-Labels` and the position of the `Y-Axis`.  Values of  `2-7` are OK here..

Comment: This works thank you! I was waiting to see if there was a way to better auto-align the Title offset to match the Y-Axis Labels.

Comment: This comes with other problems. Sample: Chart area can crop your titles. You have too know which text is for X and Y tittles. You have to guess an offset to prevent labels overlap.